# sql ant task is giving error for LDAPS oracle connection string

Tags: sql, oracle, ant

We are using ant to perform sql tasks - It has been working fine till we used LDAPS in Oracle connection string. With the Oracle LDAPS connection string as mentioned below, it is throwing the exception - `ClassNotFoundException: oracle.net.jndi.CustomSSLSocketFactory. We tried ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc14.jar - but of no use. (ant build with -v shows it is referring to ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc14.jar)`

Using the same connection string, we are able to connect through 'Oracle SQL Developer'. We changed the basePath to include sqldeveloper\jdbc\lib path but still get the same classnotfoundexception. Please advise.

Thanks
Kumar

**Environment Specifications**

```
1. Oracle: 10.2.0.4
2. Java JDK: 1.6 (Oracle GlassFish)
3. ojdbc6.jar (Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3) JDBC Drivers)
4. ojdbc14.jar (Oracle Database 10g Release 2 (10.2.0.4) JDBC Drivers )
5. OS: Windows 7 64 bit
```

**LDAPS connection string**

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://${lDAP-server}:${ldap-port}/${Schema},cn=OracleContext,dc=xxx,dc=com"
```

**SQL ant task**

```
< sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://${lDAP-server}:${ldap-port}/${Schema},cn=OracleContext,dc=xxxx,dc=com" userid="${this.service.db.user}" password="${this.service.db.password}" classpathref="base.classpath"> 
SELECT * FROM SOMETHING;
</sql>
```

**Full Exception trace:**

```
BUILD FAILED
The following error occurred while executing
 this line:
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error:
JNDI Package failure **javax.naming.CommunicationException**: servername:port (changed) [Root exception is **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.net.jndi.CustomSSLSocketFactory**]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:370)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:942)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:614)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: JNDI Package failure javax.naming.CommunicationException: server:port (changed) [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.net.jndi.CustomSSLSocketFactory]
        at oracle.net.jndi.JndiAttrs.<init>(JndiAttrs.java:161)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.<init>(AddrResolution.java:193)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:219)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        ... 64 more
```

Comment: I wonder if the LDAP server is using a self signed SSL cert? This problem tends to throw rather hard to interpret java errors :-(

Comment: Hi Mark - Thanks for taking look at it - We were able to successfully connect using a simple java program (Connection connection = establishConnection(connString, userId, password); without any SSL setup - Even the oracle admin guys mentioned we do not need a security certificate. We guess ant sql task has some invalid jar reference. As a workaround, we have created our own java sql implementation and calling it instead of the ant sql task

Answer (score 0):

Had this error running sql via sqlplus using "moten". Solved using ojdbc5.jar (from Oracle). Include this in your classpath. Check your JVM is the same version (JDK 1.5).